# How do I provision a Framework using IBDesignable classes in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store

I've created a custom Framework in order to include IBDesignable classes in my project. This works fine on the simulator, but my issue comes when trying to build for a device or archive my project. The new Framework needs to be provisioned so that it can build for a device. I am able to get it working by making a separate App ID for the Framework but that doesn't seem ideal.

I know I can use a wildcard, but eventually this will need to go to the App Store and I want to be able to use Push Notifications. Is there a way to provision both the Framework and the app with the same provisioning profile, or is it standard to have multiple App IDS and provisioning profiles for each?

Comment: You shouldn’t need to provision the framework, at least not explicitly. Did you watch the “What’s New in Interface Builder” session video? I think they go over how to make a framework.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I watched the video but I don't recall him specifically mentioning it. If you try to build for a device without codesigning the framework, you get an error from Xcode telling you you have to codesign a framework in iOS 8.

Comment: Ah, you’re right. In my current project, the framework is indeed provisioned. It just has the same developer ID and provisioning profile settings as the main project, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Does your provisioning profile use a wildcard app id?

Comment: I think so, but I don’t manage that stuff for my team, so I may be missing something.